# How to use mongodb-insert-on-duplicate-key-update?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a table with 3 columns: name, age, tm.

It has a compound index on (name, age)

If use MySQL, SQL may be like this:

```
insert into tt(name,age,tm) values('chenlong', 29, 1504437683) on duplicate key update tm = 1504437683
```

How to use in mongodb?

```
db.tt.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59abe43ade8616599017a085"), "name" : "chenlong", "age" : 29, "tm" : ISODate("2017-09-03T11:32:04.156Z") }

    db.tt.update(
        {name:'chenlong',age:29},
        {
            $set: {tm:ISODate()},
            $setOnInsert: {tm:ISODate()}
        },
        { upsert: true }
    )

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

    db.tt.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59abe43ade8616599017a085"), "name" : "chenlong", "age" : 29, "tm" : ISODate("2017-09-03T11:33:09.359Z") }
```

It's okay, column tm become newer, but add a new record, error happened.

```
db.tt.update(
    {name:'chenlong',age:30},
    {
        $set: {tm:ISODate()},
        $setOnInsert: {tm:ISODate()}
    },
    { upsert: true }
)

WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16836,
                "errmsg" : "**Cannot update 'tm' and 'tm' at the same time**"
        }
})
```

How to resolve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot modify the same path with two different operators. Also what you are attempting makes no sense. The `$set` will happen on an "update" match as well as on an "upsert/insert". The point of `$setOnInsert` is for values that you **only** want to write when the "upsert/insert" actually happens. So if you has `$setOnInsert: { created: ISODate() }`, then that would make more sense, since it was a separate property that only need be written when a "new" document is created. For a "modified" time, simply use `$set` **only**. No need for the other statement.

Comment: Thanks very much.Then I delete  $setOnInsert part ,it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
db.tt.update(
    {name:'chenlong',age:30},
    {
        $set: {tm:ISODate()}    
    },
    { upsert: true } 
)
```

If document matches it will update or upsert will occur.